# JQuery Mobile Back Button with Navigation Bar

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have navigation bar in a JQM page:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Both pages have the same `navbar`.

I have back button as below:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" >Back</a>
```

The problem is that back button will not go to the previous page prior to viewing the page, #details and #about pages are included in the history. How to disregard or exclude the two pages so that clicking back button will go to the page that load it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't since "data-rel=back" uses the browser history, hence:

1. start with "Main"
2. click "About"
3. click "Details"
4. click "About"
5. click "Back"    - returns you to "Details"
6. click "Back"    - returns you to "About"
7. click "Back"    - returns you to "Main", woohoo!

I suggest you remove the navbars on both "About" and "Details" pages, this way you only have one way to go: back to the page where you called it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that would be to make your about and details pages jquery mobile dialog pages (see [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html)).

```
<a href="foo.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

Dialog pages are not tracked in the history, which should achieve the goal you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
<script>
$('#about').click(function(){
    $('#contentDiv').html('Your content');
});
$('#details').click(function(){
    $('#contentDiv').html('Your content');
});
</script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="main">
    <div id="contentDiv" data-role="content">
    </div>
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="about" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">About</a></li>
            <li><a id="details">Details</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When using this solution, you will make sure that when you click on the back button, you go to the previous page.